# Get the currently executing script element inside a type="module" script

Tags: javascript, html

Is this even possible? i see that on non-module script tags you can use `document.currentScript` is there an equivalent for modules?

I've come across `import.meta.url` which returns the module url. Is there something similar to get the script element itself?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, though?

Comment: It’s a very niche requirement, just curious if there are any workarounds. I’m building some apps that will be injected into another document and need access to the currently executing scripts parent node.

Comment: There are cases were it's truly impossible, for example the case when two different `<script type="module">` elements in the same page `import` the same _third_ JS module - and pass-around a reference to a function (located in that third-module) into global-code which is then invoked (e.g. in an event-listener) - there would not be any `<script>` element that could be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

- When the script in-question is a JS module in its own `.js` file that's  directly loaded into a `<script type="module" src="">` with the `src=""` attribute:

  - (This is assuming the module is *not* loaded indirectly via an `import ... from 'anotherModule.js'` statement)
  - Then you can traverse the DOM and look for `<script>` elements where the `src=""` attribute matches the `import.meta.url` value.
- In all other cases, it isn't really possible - simply because the only real escape-hatch (`currentScript`) is purposefully disabled for JS modules (not that it was ever really reliable in the first place: e.g. it doesn't work when used by DOM event-listener callbacks).

---

I just thought of a possible (ugly) workaround:

1. Instantiate a [new `PerformanceObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver) in an inline non-module (global) script at the very top of the document.
2. Use it to immediately start monitoring for [`'element'` and `'resource'` event-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceEntry/entryType):

- Use `'element'` to look for any and all `<script>` elements.
- Use `'resource'` to log every HTTP request for script resources, including script modules loaded via indrect `import` statements.
- Unfortunately, while the `PerformanceResourceTiming` object does have `initiatorType` (which will just be a string value like `'script'`) it doesn't expose the actual DOM element that initiated the request, despite Chrome's DevTool's Network's "Initiator" tab showing the full chain (see fig below).
- However you *can* use the DOM to inspect the raw source of every `<script>` element and resource as it arrives and (using some ugly regex) attempt to parse every `import` statement and so build the load-chain yourself by mapping every `import.meta.url` to paths parsed via said regex.
- And then expose that log table and mapping information via a `window` extension property, e.g. `window.myScriptModuleMap`, which could look like this after it's populated:

  ```
  window.myScriptModuleMap = {
      'scripts/myModule.js': {
          importedBy: [
              'scripts/anotherModule.js'
          ],
          isSrcForScriptElement: null
      },
      'scripts/anotherModule.js': {
          importedBy: [],
          isSrcForScriptElement: /* a HTMLScriptElement obj */
      }
  };
  ```

3. So when you're inside a module, your script would use `window.myScriptModuleMap` and walk the chain:

   ```
   // scripts/myModule.js:

   function getMyScriptElement() {
       return getMyScriptElementInner( import.meta.url );
   }

   function getMyScriptElementInner( url ) {

       const entry = window.myScriptModuleMap[ url ];
       if( entry ) {
           if( entry.isSrcForScriptElement ) return entry.isSrcForScriptElement;
           else if( entry.importedBy.length === 1 ) {
               return getMyScriptElementInner( entry.importedBy[0] );
           }
           else {
               throw new Error( "TODO: Decide what to do when 2 or more modules share an import." );
           }
       }
       else {
           throw new Error( "No request log entry for \"" + url + "\"" );
       }
   }
   ```

---

Figure 1: The "Initiator chain" tab:

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Awr.png): [image]

---